# Why can't I predict 1 row of data correctly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

below with MLP I multiply numbers from 1 to 100 by sin35 and train. I'm experimenting with 5 numbers to try, it doesn't give the right result? why ?
Could the problem be due to whether it is linear or not?
The problem is simple for neural network but I can't do it here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV,cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale 
from sklearn import model_selection


from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')


import numpy as np
X = np.arange(100)
X=np.reshape(X, (-1, 1))

X.shape
y=X*np.sin(35)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.25, 
                                                    random_state=42)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
mlp_model = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes = (100,20)).fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)


c = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).reshape(5,1)


y_pred = mlp_model.predict(c)
y_pred
```

Comment: I'm not sure scaling the training data and then not scaling the prediction input is what you want.  How does the MLP perform with no scaling?

Comment: You need to replace `y_pred = mlp_model.predict(c)` to `y_pred = mlp_model.predict(X_test_scaled )`

Comment: @felice thanks but i want to know result of c?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks, i tried scaled version but, didnt work.

Comment: Explicitly showing in your question where the problems exist would help readers.  For example, I think you want `y_pred` to closely approximate `y[1:6]`, yes?  How closely? How far away are you from what you want?  If you use `solver="lbfgs"` and either not scale `X_train` or scale `c`, `y_pred` is pretty close.